Excel: Change thousands separator for Switzerland
Is it possible to change the thousands separator to a apostrophe, without changing the operating system country to Switzerland?
Correct way: 1'234'567.89 CHF
This format works in Word mail merge: #’##0,00
Format: #.##0,00 [$CHF] (Default from Excel with German operating system settings)
Output: 1.234.567,89 CHF
Output: 567,89 CHF

Format: #’##0,00 [$CHF]
Output: 1234’567,89 CHF
Output: ’567,89 CHF

Format: #'##0,00 [$CHF]
Output: 1234'567,89 CHF
Output: '567,89 CHF

In the last two examples, you can see that there is a fixed separator at the 1st thousands digit, not at other digits, and if the number is less than 1000, it is still displayed.

This method allows you to change the options in Excel instead of in the system. However, this changes all the number formats in Excel, so I am not sure if it is what you want.

@alph I know the option. So is it not possible to overwrite this or the operating system setting so that there is uniform formatting everywhere?
